# Comparing strings on character basis

Tags: javascript, string, compare

I'm trying to compare an input of strings with Vanilla JS and I need to compare them on char by char basis. And then add the string to an array if the strings are off by more than lets say 5 characters. For a more simple explanation I want to compare these strings:

- Embedded Systems part 1
- Economics part 1
- Embedded Systems part 2
- Economics Part 2
- Embedded Systems Laboration

And because I compare them on a character basis I want my array in this example to look like this after comparing all 4 strings:

```
array = [
         "Embedded Systems Part 1",
         "Economics Part 1",
         "Embedded Systems Laboration
         ]
```

So I've already tried with this code:

```
let inputLines = inputArea.value.split("\n")
let summaryArray = []
let differenceVar = 0

for(let inputLine of inputLines) {
    if (summaryArray.length == 0)   
        // Pushes the first input line, so that's in the array                   
        summaryArray.push(inputLine)
    }
    // Using this kind of loop because I want to push to the array
    // in this loop and then compare that newly pushed string to
    // the rest of the strings as well
    for (let i = 0; i < summaryArray.length; i++) {
        const arrayLine = summaryArray[i]
        for (let j = 0; j < arrayLine.length; j++) {
            const arrayChar = arrayLine[j]                       
            const inputChar = inputLine[j]
            if (arrayChar != inputChar) {
                differenceVar++
            }
        }
        if (differenceVar > 5) {
            differenceVar = 0
            summaryArray.push(inputLine)
        }
    }
}
```

I end up with this array:

```
array = ["SUMMARY:Embedded Systems Part 1",
         "SUMMARY:Economics Part 1",
         "SUMMARY:Embedded Systems Part 2",
         "SUMMARY:Economics Part 2",
         "SUMMARY:Economics Part 2",
         "SUMMARY:Embedded Systems Laboration",
         "SUMMARY:Embedded Systems Laboration",
         "SUMMARY:Embedded Systems Laboration"]
```

I understand why this happens, because it checks all the strings in the array not just the ones that are similar..

I've tried to do this with `indexOf()` but it doesn't work because there is just a bit that is of every time (almost), so it always returns -1...

Any help on how I should think regarding this problem is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
So my example probably wasn't the best although I have a hunch about how to solve my problem. But how my input lines actually look is like this:

```
array = [
         "SUMMARY:Kurs.grp: Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Sign: fni Moment: Ibs Program: Civilingenjör datateknik åk 3-",
         "SUMMARY:Kurs.grp: Ekonomi för civilingenjörer Entreprenörskap och företagande för ingenjörer Sign: msbk Moment: Fl 8 Program: Byggingenjörsprogrammet åk 3 Civilingenjör datateknik åk 3- Dataingenjörsprogrammet åk 3 Högskoleingenjör - Ind design och produktutv åk 1- Högskoleingenjör - Industriell ekonomi åk 1- Högskoleingenjör - Maskinteknik åk 1-",
         "SUMMARY:Kurs.grp: Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Sign: fni Moment: Ibs - Övning grupp 1 Program: Civilingenjör datateknik åk 3-",
         "SUMMARY:Kurs.grp: Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Sign: fni Moment: Ibs - Övning grupp 2 Program: Civilingenjör datateknik åk 3-",
         "SUMMARY:Kurs.grp: Ekonomi för civilingenjörer Entreprenörskap och företagande för ingenjörer Sign: msbk Moment: Fl 9 Program: Byggingenjörsprogrammet åk 3 Civilingenjör datateknik åk 3- Dataingenjörsprogrammet åk 3 Högskoleingenjör - Ind design och produktutv åk 1- Högskoleingenjör - Industriell ekonomi åk 1- Högskoleingenjör - Maskinteknik åk 1-",
        ]
```

This goes on for almost 40 lines..

And from these input lines I would like the output array to look like:

```
outputArray = [
               "Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer",
               "Ekonomi för civilingenjörer Entreprenörskap och företagande för ingenjörer",
              ]
```

Comment: Are the strings always in pairs like your example?

Comment: No, that maybe was a bad example, but it might look a bit more like:

    "Embedded systems part 1" 
    ,"Economics part 1" 
    ,"Embedded systems part 2" 
    ,"Economics part 2"

In reality I don't know the order of the strings

Comment: [Edit] your question to include a more reasonable example.

Comment: Thank you @HereticMonkey, I've done it know and when I tried the other example I got a better understanding of the problem.. Just don't know how to fix it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Based on your question edit, it looks like you need to parse each line to get just a particular section of text and then filter the resulting array to remove duplicates. One way to do that would be to use regex. If you still need to exclude near duplicates similar to your original question, you can add in the "matches" array step from the original answer below.

For example:

```js
const arr = ["SUMMARY:Kurs.grp: Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Sign: fni Moment: Ibs Program: Civilingenjör datateknik åk 3-", "SUMMARY:Kurs.grp: Ekonomi för civilingenjörer Entreprenörskap och företagande för ingenjörer Sign: msbk Moment: Fl 8 Program: Byggingenjörsprogrammet åk 3 Civilingenjör datateknik åk 3- Dataingenjörsprogrammet åk 3 Högskoleingenjör - Ind design och produktutv åk 1- Högskoleingenjör - Industriell ekonomi åk 1- Högskoleingenjör - Maskinteknik åk 1-", "SUMMARY:Kurs.grp: Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Sign: fni Moment: Ibs - Övning grupp 1 Program: Civilingenjör datateknik åk 3-", "SUMMARY:Kurs.grp: Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Sign: fni Moment: Ibs - Övning grupp 2 Program: Civilingenjör datateknik åk 3-", "SUMMARY:Kurs.grp: Ekonomi för civilingenjörer Entreprenörskap och företagande för ingenjörer Sign: msbk Moment: Fl 9 Program: Byggingenjörsprogrammet åk 3 Civilingenjör datateknik åk 3- Dataingenjörsprogrammet åk 3 Högskoleingenjör - Ind design och produktutv åk 1- Högskoleingenjör - Industriell ekonomi åk 1- Högskoleingenjör - Maskinteknik åk 1-"];
const lines = arr.map(line => line.match(/(?:SUMMARY:Kurs.grp:)(.+)(?:Sign:)/)[1]);
const results = lines.filter((line, i) => {
  if (!lines.slice(0, i).includes(line)) {
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
});

console.log(results);
// [" Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer Inbyggda system för civilingenjörer ", " Ekonomi för civilingenjörer Entreprenörskap och företagande för ingenjörer "]
```

ORIGINAL:

It appears that you are trying to remove strings from your array based on whether or not they start with a case-insensitive sequence of characters that is the same as a previous string in the array. If that is an accurate summary of your objective, then following is an approach you could use.

- `split()` the input text on line endings
- `map()` the resulting array
  to a corresponding array of "matches" where each line is lowercase
  and the desired number of characters are removed from the end of the
  string (5 in this case)
- `filter()` the array by checking if a
  lowercase / sliced version of the current line exists at any previous
  index in the matches array

For example:

```js
const text = `Embedded Systems part 1
Economics part 1
Embedded Systems part 2
Economics Part 2
Embedded Systems Laboration`;
  
const lines = text.split('\n');
const matches = lines.map(line => line.toLowerCase().slice(0, -5));
const results = lines.filter((line, i) => {
  if (!matches.slice(0, i).includes(line.toLowerCase().slice(0, -5))) {
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
});

console.log(results);
// ["Embedded Systems part 1", "Economics part 1", "Embedded Systems Laboration"]
```

Comment: Thank you benvc, this certainly help, maybe my new example was bad again but my real world problem is more troublesome than this, please see my new edit of what my input lines and how i want my array to look actually looks... Thanks again

Comment: @Addeuz - yes, that is a bit of a different problem. See answer edit corresponding to your updated question.

Comment: this is perfect, thank you very much! What is the thing you do in the `match()` function? Is it a regular expression? I really need to learn more about those!!

Comment: @Addeuz - yes it is a regular expression. You can copy the expression along with your text lines into a site like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and you will see a detailed explanation of how the regex works. In this case, we are using some non-capturing groups to match the delimiting strings without "capturing" them and then a normal capture group to match the text between the delimiting strings.